# How can I get one neighbourhood name using address and/or postal code?

Tags: geolocation, postal-code, address, argentina

this is my first time here.

I just need to get a neighbourhood/locality name, to get it I have the address and postal code (all over Argentina). -no polygons needed-

This is to change a background image acording to its neighbourhood/locality, this does not need to be a 100% accurate about neighbourhood/locality limits

Comment: Regardless of accuracy, you would need a data source that has neighborhood/locality boundaries to check your geocoded point against (or a service that can do it for you). Neighborhoods is usually a very fine grained level of data. You may have some luck pulling from OSM, but other than such a crowd-sourced source I think you'd be stuck contacting individual cities to see if they have a neighborhood data layer available. ArcGIS's World Geocoder service can return a neighborhood field value, but that would require they have such base data in the geocoder to match.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I could see neighbor info seems to be quite difficult to find/handle

Comment: Since the request was low priority and difficult to implement, more over the data to work with was not even 100% reliable. The request was canselled. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the International Address Verification API from SmartyStreets.com. Having never been to Argentina I'm not very familiar with their neighborhood system but here is some output from the API which some locality information, and a corresponding Google map:

#### Input:

> El Tupe No 4950
>
> Partido de la Matanza
>
> Provincia de Buenos Aires, Argentina

#### International API Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "address1":"El Tupe 4950",
      "address2":"Ciudad Evita – Partido De 1778 Ciudad Evita",
      "address3":"B1778 La Matanza",
      "components":{  
         "administrative_area":"Buenos Aires",
         "building":"Ciudad Evita – Partido De",
         "dependent_locality":"Ciudad Evita",
         "country_iso_3":"ARG",
         "locality":"La Matanza",
         "postal_code":"B1778",
         "postal_code_short":"B1778",
         "premise":"4950",
         "premise_number":"4950",
         "thoroughfare":"El Tupe",
         "sub_building_number":"1778"
      },
      "metadata":{  
         "max_geocode_precision":"Premise"
      },
      "analysis":{  
         "verification_status":"Verified",
         "address_precision":"Thoroughfare",
         "max_address_precision":"DeliveryPoint"
      }
   }
]
```

#### Map

- [Google Map zoomed to show the address and the surrounding neighborhoods](https://www.google.com/maps/place/El+Tupe,+Cdad.+Evita,+Buenos+Aires,+Argentina/@-34.7029208,-58.5607166,13.28z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x95bccf6aa2b72147:0x1dd5887f01315ba8)

What this input/output and corresponding map show is that `Cuidad Evita` (the `dependant_locality` value) is *more fine-grained neighborhood information* provided by the API (which seems to be what you are asking for). The only question is whether that information is fine-grained enough for your use case.

- [Documentation for the International API from SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/docs/cloud/international-street-api)

> Full disclosure: I'm a developer at [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), an address verification API provider.